# How can i access any key inside of json string via C#?

Tags: c#, json, soap

My question is simple but i can not do that. i wanna get value of "soap:Body" from below string by C#code?

```
{"soap:Envelope":{"xmlns:xsd":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema","xmlns:soap":"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope","xmlns:xsi":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance","soap:Body":{"ToplamaResponse":{"xmlns":"http://tempuri.org/","ToplamaResult":156758}}}}
```

Comment: Use some json parser. For exmple, JSON.NET by Newtonsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the Framework class JavaScriptSerializer if you do not want to use an external library.

```
string json = @"...";

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var o = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
var body = o["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple example in the [JObject.Parse documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm)

```
string json = @"{
  "soap:Envelope": {
    "xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
    "xmlns:soap": "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope",
    "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "soap:Body": {
      "ToplamaResponse": {
        "xmlns": "http://tempuri.org/",
        "ToplamaResult": 156758
      }
    }
  }
}";
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

Console.WriteLine((string)obj["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]);
```

And if you want to manipulate the value of "soap:Body" do the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using Json.NET

```
dynamic data = JObject.Parse("{'soap:Envelope':{'xmlns:xsd':'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','xmlns:soap':'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope','xmlns:xsi':'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance','soap:Body':{'ToplamaResponse':{'xmlns':'http://tempuri.org/','ToplamaResult':156758}}}}");

string soap_body = data["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"];
```